# How to add dynamic key in javascript object and remove that after operation has completed?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array of objects , take the below code as a example:

```
Let Data =  [
            {
              "helptext": "streetAddress_description_text",
              "name": "addressLine1",
              "label": "streetAddress_label",
              "placeholder": "streetAddress_sample",
              "type": "text",
              "required": true
            },
            {
              "helptext": "streetAddress2_descriptor_text",
              "name": "addressLine2",
              "label": "streetAddress2_label",
              "placeholder": "streetAddress2_sample",
              "type": "text",
              "required": false
            },
            {
              "name": "city",
              "label": "city_label",
              "placeholder": "city_sample",
              "type": "text",
              "required": true
            }
]
```

Here i need to add a unique value in the objects that is present inside the array.Example **id**

```
 [
            {
              "helptext": "streetAddress_description_text",
              "name": "addressLine1",
              "label": "streetAddress_label",
              "placeholder": "streetAddress_sample",
              "type": "text",
              "required": true,
               "id":1
            },
            {
              "helptext": "streetAddress2_descriptor_text",
              "name": "addressLine2",
              "label": "streetAddress2_label",
              "placeholder": "streetAddress2_sample",
              "type": "text",
              "required": false,
               "id":2
            },
            {
              "name": "city",
              "label": "city_label",
              "placeholder": "city_sample",
              "type": "text",
              "required": true,
               "id":3
            }
]
```

And i am using the above object for some operation. Take an example i am rearranging the object position. Eg:

```
 [

            {
              "name": "city",
              "label": "city_label",
              "placeholder": "city_sample",
              "type": "text",
              "required": true,
               "id":3
            },
            {
              "helptext": "streetAddress2_descriptor_text",
              "name": "addressLine2",
              "label": "streetAddress2_label",
              "placeholder": "streetAddress2_sample",
              "type": "text",
              "required": false,
               "id":2
            },
            {
              "helptext": "streetAddress_description_text",
              "name": "addressLine1",
              "label": "streetAddress_label",
              "placeholder": "streetAddress_sample",
              "type": "text",
              "required": true,
               "id":1
            }
]
```

After this process, i need to removed the **id** which we have added in the first process. And sumbiting the value to the server. Is there any way to achieve this.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Just map over the data and use `delete` to remove the key from the object.

```js
const data = [

  {
    "name": "city",
    "label": "city_label",
    "placeholder": "city_sample",
    "type": "text",
    "required": true,
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "helptext": "streetAddress2_descriptor_text",
    "name": "addressLine2",
    "label": "streetAddress2_label",
    "placeholder": "streetAddress2_sample",
    "type": "text",
    "required": false,
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "helptext": "streetAddress_description_text",
    "name": "addressLine1",
    "label": "streetAddress_label",
    "placeholder": "streetAddress_sample",
    "type": "text",
    "required": true,
    "id": 1
  }
]

const dataWithoutId = data.map(obj=>{
  const newObj = {...obj}
  delete newObj.id
  
  return newObj
})

console.log(dataWithoutId)
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Why should OP use `.map()`?